# Declaring an object that extends a class and implements more than one interface

Tags: java, object-oriented, solid

I'm confused about how should I declare an object that implements more than one interface, or derives from a class that implements one interface, and implements another interface itself.

Let's suppose I have a generic DAO interface, as follows:

```java
public interface IDao<T> {

  Optional<T> get(long id);

  List<T> getAll();

  void save(T t);

  void update(T t, String[] params);

  void delete(T t);
}
```

Then, I also have an implementation for this interface:

```java
public class DaoImpl implements IDao<Entity> {
  //implementation goes here
}
```

In my understanding, if I'd like to use this DAO implementation in another class, I should declare the object as an `IDao`, instead of `DaoImpl`, in order to be able to change the implementation without modifying the class. See below:

```java
public class MyClass {

  IDao dao;

  public MyClass(IDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }
}
```

However, suppose I want to create an implementation that extends the `DaoImpl` and adds functionality, for example:

```java
public class FilterDaoImpl extends DaoImpl implements IFilterDao<Entity> {
  public List<Entity> getBetweenDates(Date start, Date end) {
  //...
  }
}
```

I believe I should also create an `IFilterDao` interface and make the `FilterDaoImpl` implement it. I'm not sure how to declare this implementation in a class. If I do it like this:

```java
public class MyClass2 {

  IFilterDao dao;

  public MyClass(IFilterDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }
}
```

I won't be able to call methods like `getAll()`.

How should I declare the `FilterDaoImpl`implementation in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is that a FilterDao includes all of the behaviours that a regular Dao does, then you can make FilterDao extend the Dao interface. e.g.

```
public interface FilterDao extends Dao {
```

you can then extend the implementation to avoid reimplementing methods:

```
public class FilterDaoImpl extends DaoImpl implements FilterDao {
```

By the way, most Java conventions prefer not to prefix interface names with "I".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This option came to my mind, but then, the `FilterDaoImpl` would have to implement all the methods of the `Dao` and the `FilterDao`. I wanted `FilterDaoImpl` to extend `DaoImpl` just so it could use the already implemented methods of `DaoImpl`.

Comment: @PedroRates then make `FilterDao` extend `Dao`, and `FilterDaoImpl` extend `DaoImpl`.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for the insight. At least in Java, it would generate a compiler error saying something along the lines of "FilterDaoImpl is trying to implement Dao twice".

Comment: @PedroRates I'll bet you my 20+ years of experience with Java that it doesn't say that. It's redundant to redeclare an interface implemented in the superclass, but it's not an error.

Comment: @Kayaman you're right. I've just tested it and it worked just right. I tried something similar just before I posted this question and got the aforementioned error. Guess I've messed something up. Don't you want to post an answer? I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @PedroRates this is a good answer so you can just accept this one, I edited the info to it (pending review).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to have a Normal Dao which will read data from DB and then have a FilteredDao which will get Data and the apply filter and return it.

**Composition over Inheritance**

You can do this way.

- Have class IDAO

  ```
  public interface IDao {

      public String getData();
  }
  ```
- Dao Impl

  ```
  public class DaoImpl implements IDao {

         public String getData() {
         return "Hello world";
        }
    }
  ```
- IFilterDao

  ```
  public interface IFilterDao {

      public String getFilteredData();
  }
  ```
- IFilterDaoImpl

  ```
  public class IFilterDaoImpl implements IFilterDao {

      private IDao iDao;

      public String getFilteredData() {
          String data =  iDao.getData();
          //apply some filter
         return data;
      }
  }
  ```

Now the IFilterDaoImpl will have all the functionality of IDAO. No matter what impl of DAO being used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that in some cases one would prefer getting the data already filtered than filtering it in memory. I was thinking about the latter when I asked this question.